# Creating Dynamic Pages with php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I am creating a list of links in main.php using "donemler" table in mySQL database and would like to create a page that shows data from "sikkeler" table (which has a foreing key donemID that is used as a relationship between the two tables) as the user clicks it. (data.php is a part of the index.php which is a infinite scroll page)

Here I tried to call `$row["donemID"]` with GET method using
`$k=$_GET['donemID']` in index.php but did not work.

I have also tried to use SESSIONS method where I add    "`$_SESSION['donemID']=$row$row["donemID"]` to main.php

and called it back in index.php as 
`$k=$_SESSION['donemID']`

but it also did not work.

I would like to learn how to create pages and show relevant data in php.

Thanks in advance!

main.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM donemler ORDER BY donemID");

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr><td><a href='index.php?devletID=".$row["devletID"]."&donemID=".$row["donemID"]."'>" .$row["donemler"]. "</a></td></tr>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var start = 0;
        var limit = 20;
        var reachedMax = false;
        var dnmID = $_GET("donemID");

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() )

                getData();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
           getData();
        });

        function getData() {
            if (reachedMax)
                return;

            $.ajax({
               url: 'data.php',
               method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
               data: {
                   getData: 1,
                   start: start,
                   limit: limit,
                   dnmID: dnmID,
               },
               success: function(response) {
                    if (response == "reachedMax")
                        reachedMax = true;
                    else {
                        start += limit;
                        $(".results").append(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

data.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['getData']) ) {

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'usrnm', 'pss', 'db');

    $dnmID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['dnmID']);
    $start = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['start']);
    $limit = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['limit']);

    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM sikkeler WHERE donemID='$dnmID' ORDER BY kayit_no DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
        $response = "";

        while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {
            $response .= '


<tr>
           <td>ICD#'.$data['kayit_no'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['donemi'].'</td>
           <td><img src="coin_images/'.$data['resim'].'" border="2" width="200px" /></td>
           <td>'.$data['darp'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['tarih'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['birim'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['agirlik'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['cap'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['tip'].'</td>
           <td>'.$data['reference'].'</td>


            </tr>
            ';
        }

        exit($response);
    } else
        exit('reachedMax');
}
```

?>

Comment: `$k=$_SESSION('donemID')` should be `$k=$_SESSION['donemID']` should also be `$_SESSION['donemID']=$row["donemID"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking through two different request methods:

1. `$_POST['getData']`
2. `$k=$_GET['donemID']`

Since you are using the query strings, it is a **GET** method to check with.
There is no such variable i.e. **getData** on `main.php`

Comment: index.php is a part of a page that posts its content (its a infinite scroll page). Then how can I use the GET method?

Comment: I realized that the other part of the code is actually required. So I arranged my data properly only need I need to figure out "var dnmID = $_GET("donemID");" part in the index.php now.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I realized that my problem is became "Get URL Parameters With JavaScript" and found the answer here: https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/